# Quartz 2D Drawing String in Rect, how can I get an ellipsis?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, quartz-2d

```
[infoText drawInRect:CGRectMake(10, 10, 310, 40) withFont:infoTextFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Any suggestions on how to produce an ellipsis when the text exceeds the size of the rect?

Comment: Just to clarify: You're looking to both wrap text within the rect, and truncate the text when the wrapped text reaches the bottom right of the rect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed this one in the docs... UILineBreakModeTailTruncation